# Write data in xlsm using OpenTBS

Tags: xlsm, opentbs, tinybutstrong

I'm trying fill data in .xlsm template, which contain lot of VBA calculations. When I open merged file in MS Excel, file is corrupted and Application propose repair it. After repairing, I see new blank sheet, and lost formatting in old sheet which I've merge.

In debug I see this :

```
* Deleted files in the archive:
  - xl/calcChain.xml
* Added files in the archive: none
* Modified files in the archive:
  - xl/_rels/workbook.xml.rels
  - xl/sharedStrings.xml
  - xl/worksheets/sheet1.xml
  - [Content_Types].xml
```

What i do wrong ? Or maybe OpenTBS does not support .xlsm format ?

Comment: OpenTBS does support XLSM as well as XLSX. There is a new OpenTBS version 1.9.9 that fixes a bug with such templates, could yo test it and tell if it makes a difference for you ?

Comment: I've tried - no difference. Template has one hidden sheet with lot of data and one sheet where need to fill variables. Also it has password-protected VBA scripts. I'm trying even just simply LoadTemplate and without any merging Show(OPENTBS_FILE,$path). Original template size is about 2MB. New file has size 1.4MB and sheet that was hidden now is visible, but all data empty. Visible sheet has lost some formatting (cells width) but keep colors. Also, it took a long time for LoadTemplate - about 70 seconds.

Comment: Could you send to me the template, or an arranged template that reproduces the problem ? Email: http://www.tinybutstrong.com/onlyyou.html